# Link in news feed story does not link to native iOS App, when user didn't enter an additional text.

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed, facebook-wall

In my iOS iPad app, users can post to their Facebook timeline and share their score using FBWebDialogs. Other users can tap on the link in the post and either the AppStore will open or - if installed - my native app itself will open.

I found out that opening my native app (if installed) from Facebook posts only works, when the user did enter some text in the sharing dialog. If there is no text in the dialog, Facebook App will open the AppStore app and display the app instead my native app - even if my app is installed on the iPad.

In my params to the FBWebDialog, link is set to AppStore URL, have my AppID included and deeplinking is turned on in the settings.

Anybody know about a solution to this?
Thanks for any hint!